# Javascript partial wildcard matching in a json sitemap

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I am working on a project that has a language switch. So it will pick up the current url, loop through a json object and return its language pair.

so

```
/en/cookie-policy
/de/cookie-richtlinie
```

the problem I am going to face now -- is accepting a wildcard -- like an id matching pair

so instead of hardcoding in the json all possible id's

```
/en/virtual-conference-room/1
/de/virtuellier-konferenz-raum/1
```

I want to place a kind of wildcard in the json -- that will transcribe the language pair but retain the desired id

so

```
/en/virtual-conference-room/[:num]
/de/virtuellier-konferenz-raum/[:num]
```

then I do the language switch/pair match -- produce a wildcard result for id 1, 234, 1000 etc..

I think its a case of creating an else if -- and at that point allow the wildcard match pair to be expressed, but not sure where to start.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/77/)

```
function getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
    if (obj[k].link === pairUrl) {
      if (currentLng === 'de') {
        return enMenu[k].link // get en link equivlant
      } else {
        return deMenu[k].link // get de link equivlant
      }
    } else if (paritalmatch) { 
        //finds a wild card match and allows a pair match
    }
    else {
      if (!obj[k].hasOwnProperty('children') || obj[k].children.length <= 0) continue;
      var ret = getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu[k].children, deMenu[k].children, obj[k].children);
      if(typeof ret != 'undefined') return ret;
    }
  }
}


function getLanguagePair(currentLng, pairUrl) {
  //  'find url in json tree'
  var enMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[1].lines.menu
  var deMenu = linkTreeObject.langs[0].lines.menu

  let obj = {}
    // find position in tree
  if (currentLng === 'de') {
    obj = deMenu
  } else {
    obj = enMenu
  }

  return getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj)
}

//works
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/how-it-works"))
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/virtual-conference-room/1"))
console.log(getLanguagePair("en", "/en/virtual-conference-room/2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expression to archive result that you want. The original idea is replacing each wildcard in the link with its corresponding regular expression. Then we could use regular expression to compare between two strings.
Example:

```
(1) Url: /en/virtual-conference-room/1  
(2) Link: /en/virtual-conference-room/[:num]  
(3) Regex: /en/virtual-conference-room/(\d+)
```

If regular expression (3) is matched with Url (1), then we could get corresponding link and replace wildcards with matched values.

I've created an update of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/87/), please check.

Comment: you have a stack of ifs in the getUrl function - would these be better as if, elseif, else conditions? http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/84/

Comment: - Would this work if you had a url like /en/service/[:num]/borderline

Comment: It's not different, because inside each IF it should return value, so the following IF will not be reached. It' ok if you want to update to use IF... ELSE.  The wildcard doesn't have to at the end of link, so it will work for a url like  /en/service/[:num]/borderline

Comment: your code breaks on the other url matches -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/86/   -- console.log(getLanguagePair("de", "/de/beliebte-projekte/compliance/compliance-pruefung-kmu"))  -- won't get resolved

Comment: old code able to resolve the deep nests -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/85/

Comment: -- this guy below has just added a tail to the end fragment -- http://jsfiddle.net/jg4cgkm8/

Comment: I forgot to add anchor "^" (start string) and "$" (end string)  to regular expression, so it get incorrect result when exist the similar links. I've updated demo, please check http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/87/

Comment: your wildcard replacing seems a bit complex -- would it make more sense just to use a regex variable in the url itself - so instead of [:num] just have it (\d+)

Comment: Yes, we could use regex directly in url. I just thought you want to use wildcard. Here is a demo with regex inside url http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/88/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/89/ -- your version does work if the :num is in another part of the url fragment

Comment: It's returned "/de/444/audiorits" for "getLanguagePair("en", "/en/444/soundroom")". Both strings is at 4th item of array. Is it incorrect result?

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate the code into my project -- but I am getting an undefined return on the video conference room -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/91/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148040/discussion-between-trung-duong-and-the-old-county).

Comment: -resolved in my project I have another parameter - the json tree to do the lookup on

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this: http://jsfiddle.net/jg4cgkm8/

I've removed `[:num]` as unnecessary from here:

```
{
   "title": "Virtual Conference Room",
   "link": "/en/virtual-conference-room/"
}
```

And updated `function getUrl` as below:

```
function getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu, deMenu, obj) {
  for (let k in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
    if (pairUrl.indexOf(obj[k].link) === 0) {
      var tail = pairUrl.substr(obj[k].link.length);
      if (currentLng === 'de') {
        return enMenu[k].link + tail // get en link equivlant
      } else {
        return deMenu[k].link + tail // get de link equivlant
      }
    }
    else {
      if (!obj[k].hasOwnProperty('children') || obj[k].children.length <= 0) continue;
      var ret = getUrl(pairUrl, currentLng, enMenu[k].children, deMenu[k].children, obj[k].children);
      if(typeof ret != 'undefined') return ret;
    }
  }
}
```

Where `if (pairUrl.indexOf(obj[k].link) === 0)` checks if `pairUrl` begins from `obj[k].link` and `var tail` contains the rest of the `pairUrl` if any.

Then resulting link is corresponding equivalent + tail.

Hope it helps.